# Find, copy and paste search engine in Excel

Tags: excel, search-engine, vba

I'm trying to create a macro that would search the value of the cell B5 in a sheet called DB and paste all of the results in a sheet called Research. The idea is to copy every line that match the keyword and to paste them starting at B11 in the DB sheet.

I don't know if it's possible, but thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Get started on some code (the [macro recorder](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Step-1-Start-with-the-macro-recorder-6DC53056-1DE1-4483-AA07-63E4E0EFE3C2) should be a good start) then come back with your copde if you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sub CreateList()

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim I As Integer
Dim J As Integer
Dim srchtxt As String
Dim celltxt As String



'Determines last row of database worksheet to know what range to loop through
LastRow = Worksheets("DB").Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Gets the text or value to be searched
srchtxt = Worksheets("SearchWS").Range("B5") '***Change cell to search

'Clear research sheet, the destination sheet
Worksheets("Research").Cells.Clear

'Activate DataBase sheet
Worksheets("DB").Activate

'Loops through and copies all rows with desired value or text, pasting them in the research sheet. j keeps track of the next empty row.
'The InStr and UCase ensure capitalization doesn't cause a problem. You may not want this if you need exact match.
J = 2 '*** Change the first row to paste
For I = 2 To LastRow
    celltxt = Worksheets("DB").Cells(I, 1).Text 'Gets the value from the DB worksheet ***Change the column to seach in
    If InStr(1, UCase(celltxt), UCase(srchtxt)) Then 'Compares it to the specified text, B5 in this case
    Worksheets("DB").Range(Cells(I, 1), Cells(I, 2)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Research").Cells(J, 1)
    'Copies the range above. ***Change the range to copy, from 1 to 2
    J = J + 1
End If
Next I 'Loops through

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

End Sub

Comment: Hello Jcarroll, Thanks a lot for the answer, i'm not sure how the code works. How do you launch de macro and on which cell do you index the word you are searching? Thanks again!

Comment: @SalimChorfi Please see my updated answer, it should be more useful now. But let me know if you have more questions.